# How to combine two different raster attribute tables into one table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

How to combine two different raster attribute tables into one table? There is no common value.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! If you haven't taken the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), please do so. If you want others to help you, help them with giving a detailed description of your problem including screenshots, expected solution, etc.

Comment: You need to add a lot more information and ideally some screen shots. For example you have missed out the most important bit of information, what do the values represent? Are they categorical like land cover or continuous like rainfall?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS' [Combine tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) does exactly what you need. Notice that the output raster values will not necessarily match either of your input rasters, but each input raster's associated values will be in the attribute table.